# Adding a class to all elements that match a given dataset in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move away from jQuery and to plain JavaScript, and I'm having trouble understanding how to do something. I want to have a very flexible script that will allow for multiple buttons to toggle the same menu. At first, I had this working with:

```
// function to add active classes on a menu and it's associated button
function toggle_menu() {
    var active_class = "is-active";
    var target_menu = this.dataset.menu;
    var button_class_list = this.classList;
    var menu_class_list = document.querySelector("[data-menu=" + target_menu + "]").classList;

    button_class_list.toggle(active_class);
    menu_class_list.toggle(active_class);
}

// fire toggle_menu when any menu-button is clicked
document.querySelector(".menu-button").addEventListener("click", toggle_menu);
```

But after thinking about it, I realized that this could allow for the menu and the buttons to get out of sync. So now my plan is to sync all instances of the buttons and the menus, such as that when you click one button, all buttons with the same `[data-menu]` get toggled to the same state.

But I'm confused as to how to go about this. I thought if I where to do something like

```
document.querySelector("[data-menu=" + target_menu + "]").toggleClass("is-active");
```

it would work fine, but turns out that's only affecting the first instances of a matching element, not all matching elements.

How can I change this so that all elements on the page with the same `data-menu` attribute always keep their `is-active` classes in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var selected = document.querySelectorAll("[data-menu=" + target_menu + "]");
Array.from(selected).forEach(function(item){
    item.classList.toggle("is-active");
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-menu=" + target_menu + "]");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
  elems[i].toggleClass("is-active");
}
```

This is the same as querySelector, but it returns all instances instead of just the first

Comment: except you're gonna have to iterate over the results; `toggleClass` is not defined for `NodeList`s

Comment: my mistake @Hamms, I copied and pasted his code without really taking a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Please check [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first
>   pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified
>   group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.